# Maven Target folder properties

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am working on a basic maven project. This is what I get within the `target` folder

[image: Elements within target folder]

This is the outputDirectory of my maven project and I know that there is a way to change the location of the war file being generated. The folder being selected in the above picture is exactly the same as the one being deployed to the webapps folder.

[image]

Now my doubt is Can I change the location of this file so that I can instruct maven to directly generate this folder inside my `webapps` folder

Comment: Why would you like to change the location of the war file ? What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the target you want to achieve is to copy your artifact to web-server deploy directory on build.

maven-resources-plugin can be used for that

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>copy-resources</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${tomcat_home}/webapps</outputDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/eBuddy</directory>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myDirectory</id>
        <build>
            <directory>your-preffered-directory</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

mvn compile -PmyDirectory